# backend data is not displaying in webpage even though data is fetched correctly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, backend, fetch-api

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const StudentList = (props) => {

  const history = useNavigate();

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');

  const getMembers = async () => {
    try {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      if (!token) {
        alert('Authorization token not found', 'danger');
        return;
      }
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/login/get-students", {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
      const json = await response.data;
      console.log(json); // Log the response data to see its structure
      setData(json);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(`Some error occurred: ${error.message}`, 'danger');
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      getMembers();
    } else {
      history('/');
    }
  }, []);

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    setSearchQuery(event.target.value);
  };


// created members just to see if my frontend page is working fine
  const members = [{
    name: "Hamza", father: "Khan", username: "hamza", department: "CS", batch: "2021", semester: "9", password: "1234", cnic: "35202-27891-101", rollNO: "0072",
  }, {
    name: "Hamza", father: "Khan", username: "hamza", department: "CS", batch: "2021", semester: "9", password: "1234", cnic: "35202-27891-101", rollNO: "0072",
  }, {
    name: "Hamza", father: "Khan", username: "hamza", department: "CS", batch: "2021", semester: "9", password: "1234", cnic: "35202-27891-101", rollNO: "0072",
  }, {
    name: "Hamza", father: "Khan", username: "hamza", department: "CS", batch: "2021", semester: "9", password: "1234", cnic: "35202-27891-101", rollNO: "0072",
  },]

  const filteredData = data.filter((member) =>
    member.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) ||
    member.department.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) ||
    member.rollNO.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) ||
    member.father.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) ||
    member.cnic.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) ||
    member.semester.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) ||
    member.batch.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase())
  );

  return (

    <>
      <div className='container'>
        <h3 className='text-center' style={{ borderBottom: "1px solid rgb(187, 174, 174)" }} >Student List</h3>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Search...."
            value={searchQuery}
            onChange={handleSearch}
          />
        </div>
        {filteredData.length > 0 ? (
          <table className="table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr className='text-center'>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Father</th>
                <th scope="col">Roll #</th>
                <th scope="col">Batch</th>
                <th scope="col">Username</th>
                <th scope="col">Semester</th>
                <th scope="col">Cnic</th>
                <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                <th scope="col">Remove</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {filteredData.map((val, key) => (
                <tr key={filteredData._id}>
                  <td>{val.name}</td>
                  <td>{val.father}</td>
                  <td>{val.rollNO}</td>
                  <td>{val.batch}</td>
                  <td>{val.username}</td>
                  <td>{val.semester}</td>
                  <td>{val.cnic}</td>
                  <td>Edit</td>
                  <td>Remove</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        ) : (
          <div>No matching members found.</div>
        )}
      </div>

    </>
  )
}

export default StudentList;
```

I'm fetching data using axios and it's fetching correctly ... I've checked console it's showing students data the data is stored in mongodb but when I'm trying to display data on web page it's saying data.filter in filteredData function is not a function as data is undefined .... I've replaced data with members it's working fine

Comment: There is no need of `await` infront of `response.data`, can you also share what do you see in the `console.log(json)`

Comment: Your `data` starts as an empty array in the state, so `data.filter()` cannot be undefined, then you fetch from API and put it inside `data`. Is  the response from the API an array? Where are you logging `data` exactly?

Comment: Most likely because your `response.data` is not an array.

Comment: Can you share your response? The only reason would be the response.data is not an array.

Comment: I got it the response was an object and i was directly mapping the data object ... but i should've used data.members it's now working when I'm using  Array.from(data.members).filter  Thanks a lot for you're comments that's what gave me the solution